# SSD temperature increment when switch IDE to AHCI

Tags: windows-10, ssd, temperature, ide, ahci

I have a notebook with a Kingston KC600 256GB SSD inside.

I had it running in IDE mode, so it was limited to 400 MB/s, but it had 30 ºC when no usage, and 40 ºC at full usage.

Now i switched it to AHCI (in Windows 10 registry and BIOS) and im getting better performance 550 MB/s (nearest to SATA 3 theoric performance), but its temperature growed to 40 ºC when idle, and 50 ºC at full usage.
Thats 10 ºC added just by switching IDE to AHCI.

I think my notebook has broken CPU fan, because my notebook was getting hotter years ago, and CPU fan disappeared from SpeedFan (hardware monitor app). So i bought a cooler base and its doing "ok".

I get 50 - 70 ºC CPUs temp (0% - 100% usage)
And like i said, 40 - 50 ºC SSD temp (0% - 100% usage)

So my questions are:

1. Is it normal? Im scared because i wouldnt like to expose my SSD to that temperature...
2. Could it be drivers issue? I ran Windows update and it says its all up to date.
3. Any advices on how to lower temperature?

Comment: "I think my notebook has broken CPU fan" … so get the fan fixed. It's a bit like asking the car mechanic to fix the horn because the brakes don't work.

Comment: How many time has passed since you switched to AHCI and how much time was your computer running in that duration?

Comment: @Tetsujin but fixing the fan isnt that easy as other solutions

Comment: @Robert i switched to AHCI 2 days ago, and it ran maybe 20 hours

Comment: An SSD drive under 70ºC is generally within the operating parameters provided by manufacturers, and yours is only up to 50ºC.

Comment: @harrymc yes, 70 ºC is the max acceptable, so 50 ºC appears to be ok...
But better 40 ºC at 100% than 50ºC.

Comment: The temperature is fine, dont worry about it and use it at its full capabilities. Since heat is pushed out by the CPU fan for the entire laptop, replacing the fan might have a positive effect on SSD temperature as well.